# Converting Recorded VLookUp formula in R1C1 into VBA formula using A1 reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this recorded macro that I want to convert to plain VBA macro code and copy the formula from `AE2` to lastrow.

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'[test.xlsx]Sheet3'!C5:C6,2,0)" ' this is from another workbook
```

Trying to convert to VBA.

```
dim wbSLW as workbook
dim wbSLWDir as String

wbSLWDir = "C\Documents\test.xlsx" 'this is not the constant directory or file name
set wbSLW  = workbooks.open(wbSLWDir)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
With Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)
   .Range("AE2") = "=VLOOKUP(I2," & wbSLW & "!E:F,2,0)" ' error line
end with
```

When I've converted it, it returns `Object does not support this property or method`.

Comment: You converted RC[-22] to I2 so you have to convert the remainder in the same way. Just follow the same principle.

Comment: @SJR So I have to convert all the codes?

Comment: Actually I think R3uK has done it for you.

Comment: Yep, Thanks. Got it :)

Comment: Since your `Activecell`is `AE`, then `C[-30]:C[-29]` means that your looking up in `A:B` columns.

Comment: @ramedju : Btw, please don't use the tag [tag:macros] read the info about it, you'll that it isn't for [tag:VBA]! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I'm sorry. I've accidentally clicked it :) Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned recorded code :

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("AE2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-22],Temp!C[-30]:C[-29],2,0)"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE182"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With 'ActiveSheet
```

---

`RC[-22]` refers to a cell that is 22 columns before the cell in which you have the formula
 here `AE2` is the initial cell, so `RC[-22]`=`I2`

`C[-30]` and `C[-29]`  refers respectively to columns that are 30 and 29 columns before the cell in which you have the formula
here `AE2`, so `C[-30]`=`A` and `C[-29]`=`B`

Changed formula :

```
Sheets(1).Range(perNum & 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I2,Temp!A:B,2,0)"
```

or without converting the formula :

```
Sheets(1).Range(perNum & 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-22],Temp!C[-30]:C[-29],2,0)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It makes me understand more the `VLookUp` function in Excel. :)

Comment: @ramedju : See the edit! You didn't even have to convert your formula to use it in VBA! ;)

Comment: @ramedju : First, you are obviously missing a `.Formula`, then built it manually and you'll see that you need to have both the Workbook.FullName (path + name) and the name of the sheet! Try it and if it doesn't work, post a new question and then you can come back here to poke me with the link of the new question! ;)

Comment: It worked but it opens an OpenFile Dialog box. But the workbook is already open, my `wbSLW ` variable in my above question opens the workbook. Thanks

Comment: @ramedju : Like I said, construct the formula MANUALLY to see how it should be! Then use `wbSLW.FullName`! I won't comment more on that new issue in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Change your settings so that it does not use R1C1 format by going to (Excel 2010)  Settings / Formulas and then unchecking the R1C1 reference style. Rerecord your macro and then edit it. You should not have any "RC" references, but if you do then change all references that have "RC" in them to the the same style as in "I2".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Active Sheet name is `Sheet1`

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2"), Sheets("Temp").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
```

Comment: With that you'll only have the value in there and not the formula!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to replace name of the workbook in below line in `vba` code :

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'[**test.xlsx**]Sheet3'!C5:C6,2,0)
```

Simplest way to do that without changing any other code is :

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'[**" & wbSLW.Name & "**]Sheet3'!C5:C6,2,0)
```